# Upload a video to youtube from a url with php

Tags: php, codeigniter, video, youtube

I have built an application in CodeIgniter. The user will be able to log in and upload a video. This video is hosted in a platform and I can take this URL. I have solved the connection between the application and Google account with the oauth2 protocol. My problem is how I will be able with one click to upload the video from the hosting to Youtube by using the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Since the source is external, I suggest to first download the video to your local server using [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) then upload to youtube.

Uploading is very well documented see [`Uploading videos`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php#Uploading_Videos)